# Magento 1.9.1 swatches not display after enabled

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

Currently i just upgrade to magento 1.9.1 and using the guide from

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches

i have upload 2 png file namely Black and White to [your Magento install dir]/media/wysiwyg/swatches.

But under my webpage, it is still showing me a dropdown box instead of swatches? Is it because of the theme that i use which is not compatible to magento 1.9.1 swatches ?

Under my configurable products, the image i have also label to White and Black. What can be wrong.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to refresh the Swatch Images Cache. It's a new button under System > Cache Management. Also use **lowercase** only for swatch image file names, like `white.png` and `black.png`

I have also found that swatches only work under the RWD package and not the DEFAULT package which comes with Magento. So if you are using a custom theme, it is very likely that the swatches don't work out of the box. Contact your theme developer to update the theme and integrate swatches.

You could run a test by switching to the RWD package temporarily, to check if swatches then work.

Comment: I see. Maybe it only applicable for RWD theme like what you suggested. My theme that i am using is a free theme, i doubt they will support =(

Comment: @KelvinLowKokHoe I got the swatches working for the DEFAULT package. You can find a write-up on how I did this [via this link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a). Maybe this will work for your theme too