# How to use Magento 1.9.1.0 Configurable Swatches in Default package theme (or a custom theme)?

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.1.0, swatches, color-swatches

> **UPDATE:** My answer now supports automated change of the product base
>   image after swatch. You can also find a more detailed tutorial on how
>   to do this including more images
>   [here](http://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/use-magento-swatches-in-custom-theme/).

Magento CE 1.9.1.0 comes with a very nice new feature: Configurable Swatches. Unfortunately, this is only available for the RWD package, that comes with the default Magento installation.
This is a self answered question on how to make the Magento Configurable Swatches available for the Default package. For anyone who wants to integrate the Configurable Swatches
into a custom theme, this info may come in handy as well.

**Note 1:** This is meant to be an introductional guide on how to make the Configurable Swatches available for Magento's Default package. This could (but may not) work for every custom theme.
Always backup your original files (and database) before making any changes.

<strike>**Note 2:** The swatches do work (screen shot below), but I did not yet get the product image to change automatically along with the swatches. I will try and look into this when I find some time.</strike>

[image]

Feel free to contribute by commenting and make suggestions!

Comment: The link you added in the question is not working: http://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/use-magento-swatches-in-custom-theme/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Copy the folder

   ```
   app/design/frontend/RWD/default/template/configurableswatches/
   ```

   and its content to

   ```
   app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/template/
   ```

   (or your package template folder)
2. Copy the file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/RWD/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/
   ```

   (or your package template folder)
3. Copy the file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/RWD/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/template/catalog/product/view/
   ```

   (or your package template folder)
4. Copy the folders

   ```
   skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/configurableswatches/
   skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/lib/
   ```

   and their content to

   ```
   skin/frontend/DEFAULT/default/js/
   ```

   (or your package skin folder)
5. Copy the files

   ```
   skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/app.js
   skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/minicart.js
   skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/slideshow.js
   ```

   to

   ```
   skin/frontend/DEFAULT/default/js/
   ```

   (or your package skin folder)
6. Copy the file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/RWD/default/layout/configurableswatches.xml
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/layout/
   ```

   (or your package layout folder)
7. Create the file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/layout/local.xml
   ```

> If your package layout folder already contains a `local.xml` file,
>   then do not overwrite it. Have a look at the changes in the next step
>   and copy them to your version of the `local.xml` file.

8. Open up `local.xml` and add the following code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout>

       <default>

           <reference name="head">

                   <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
                   <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>

                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/selectivizr.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/enquire.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
           <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>

           </reference>

       </default>

       <catalog_product_view>

           <reference name="head">

               <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</script></action>

           </reference>

           <reference name="product.info.media">

               <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.media.after" as="after" />

           </reference>

       </catalog_product_view>

       <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>

           <reference name="product.info.options.configurable">

               <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers">
                           <block type="configurableswatches/catalog_product_view_type_configurable_swatches" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml" />
               </block>
               <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after">
               <block type="core/template" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/configurable/swatch-js.phtml" />
               </block>

           </reference>

       </PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>

   </layout>
   ```
9. Add the following css to your **styles.css** file:

   ```
   /* ============================================ *
    * Configurable Swatches
    * ============================================ */
   /* Clears */
   .clearfix:after,
   .configurable-swatch-list:after,
   .product-view .product-options .swatch-attr:after {
     content: '';
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }

   /* General Swatch Styling */
   .swatch-link,
   .swatch-label {
     display: block;
     border-radius: 3px;
     font-size: 14px;
     text-align: center;
     color: #636363;
     text-decoration: none;
     box-sizing: content-box;
   }

   .swatch-link {
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     margin: 0 0 3px;
   }
   .swatch-link img {
     border-radius: 2px;
   }
   .swatch-link:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
   .swatch-link .x {
     display: none;
     text-indent: -999em;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     background: url(../images/bg_x.png) center no-repeat transparent;
     z-index: 10;
   }
   .swatch-link.has-image .swatch-label {
     position: relative;
   }
   .swatch-link.has-image img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
   }

   .swatch-label {
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     margin: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
     background: #f4f4f4;
   }

   .configurable-swatch-list {
     margin-left: -3px;
     zoom: 1;
     clear: both;
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
   }
   .configurable-swatch-list li {
     float: left;
     zoom: 1;
     margin: 0 0 0 3px;
   }
   .products-grid .configurable-swatch-list li {
     display: inline-block;
     float: none;
     margin: 0;
     vertical-align: top;
   }
   .configurable-swatch-list .not-available .x {
     display: block;
   }
   .configurable-swatch-list .not-available .swatch-link {
     border-color: #ededed;
     position: relative;
   }
   .configurable-swatch-list .not-available .swatch-link.has-image img {
     opacity: 0.4;
     filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   }
   .configurable-swatch-list .not-available .swatch-label {
     color: #aaa;
     background: #fff;
   }
   .configurable-swatch-list .wide-swatch .swatch-label {
     padding: 0 6px;
   }
   .configurable-swatch-list .not-available a:focus {
     outline: 0;
   }

   #narrow-by-list dd .configurable-swatch-list li {
     margin: 0 0 0 3px;
     width: 47%;
   }
   #narrow-by-list dd .swatch-link {
     border: none;
     line-height: 25px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     text-align: left;
   }
   #narrow-by-list dd .swatch-link.has-image {
     line-height: inherit;
   }
   #narrow-by-list dd .swatch-link:hover .swatch-label {
     border-color: #3399cc;
   }
   #narrow-by-list dd .swatch-label {
     background: #f4f4f4;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     border-radius: 3px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     line-height: 1.5em;
     margin: 0 5px 0 0;
     padding: 1px 5px;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   #narrow-by-list dd .swatch-label img {
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-sizing: content-box;
   }
   #narrow-by-list dd .has-image .swatch-label {
     padding: 0;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
     #narrow-by-list dd .configurable-swatch-list li:nth-child(odd) {
       clear: left;
     }
   }
   .currently .swatch-current {
     position: relative;
   }
   .currently .swatch-current .btn-remove {
     margin-top: -10px;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 50%;
   }
   .currently .swatch-current span {
     display: block;
     float: left;
   }
   .currently .swatch-link {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 0 0 3px;
   }
   .currently .swatch-link:hover {
     border-color: #cccccc;
     cursor: default;
   }

   /* Other Swatch States */
   .configurable-swatch-list .hover .swatch-link,
   .configurable-swatch-list .selected .swatch-link,
   .swatch-link:hover {
     border-color: #3399cc;
   }

   .configurable-swatch-box {
     background: none !important;
   }
   .configurable-swatch-box select.swatch-select {
     display: none;
   }
   .configurable-swatch-box .validation-advice {
     margin: 0 0 5px;
     background: #df280a;
     padding: 2px 5px !important;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #fff !important;
     float: left;
     display: block;
     border-radius: 3px;
   }
   .product-view .product-img-box .product-image img {
       max-width: 100%;
       max-height: 750px;
       margin: 0px auto;
   }
   .product-view .product-img-box .product-image-zoom {
       z-index: 0;
   }
   .product-view .product-image-thumbs img {
       max-width: 100%;
       max-height: 100%;
   }
   ```
10. Copy the file

    ```
    skin/frontend/RWD/default/images/bg_x.png
    ```

    to

    ```
    skin/frontend/DEFAULT/default/images/
    ```

Comment: How would you add the swatches to the individual products on Catalog/Product/List? Within default RWD you are able to select the different swatches straight from here without having to click into the product. Of course, you have to have the setting enabled in the backend: "Product Attribute to Use for Swatches in Product Listing" first.

Comment: In addition, I would recommend adding `.product-image-zoom.zoom-available .gallery-image {
 display: none;
}
.product-image-zoom.zoom-available .gallery-image.visible {
 display: block;
}` to the CSS' end, as without it, you will see the last added product image when visiting a product, but when hovering, you will see the main image.

Comment: Gallery Image is not changing on click of swatch color, can you please tell me what how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

your solution is great but not show color swatch in category list or grid.  Here I add the solution to show it, tested on magento 1.9.2.4.

In : app/design/frontend/CUSTOM-THEME/template/catalog/product add followed line in **list.phtml**

1 - first to show in list view, check if there this, if no, update o change (aroud line 39):

```
<?php $_imgSize = 300; ?>
            <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                 src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
        </a>
```

In alternative can use this:

```
            <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
          src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(230,279); ?>" class="small-image" 
          alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />             

        </a>
```

adjust resize image.

2 - after "getRatingSummary" =php end if=, around line 53, add this:

```
                        <?php
                    // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                    // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                    if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                            echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

3 - make the same change to gird view around line 120 and 152.

4 - in the end of the file add this:

```
 <?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        //set product collection on after blocks
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
        echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was very helpful! I have some extra details that I was able to work through to get the image switching to work.

1. Copy the file

   ```
   app/design/frontend/RWD/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/template/catalog/product/view/
   ```

   or your custom theme
2. Copy the following list of files:

   ```
   app/skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/app.js
   app/skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/slideshow.js
   app/skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/lib/* (all files and the elevatezoom folder)
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/skin/frontend/DEFAULT/default/js
   ```

   or your custom theme
3. To include these new scripts, edit app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/layout/page.xml (make a backup of this file first and make sure to merge changes if you do updates as the default theme would be overwritten)

   Add after line 38:

   ```
   <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
   ```

   Add after line 50 (line 52 if you've already added the above two lines):

   ```
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/selectivizr.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/enquire.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
   ```
4. Remove the /* Product Images */ section from your **styles.css** file (around lines 783-803) and paste in the following CSS from the RWD styles.css file:

   ```
   * Product Images */
   .product-img-box {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
   }
   .product-img-box .product-name h1 {
     border: 0;
   }
   .product-img-box .product-image {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
   .product-img-box .product-image img {
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 750px;
     margin: 0px auto;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
     .product-img-box .product-image img {
       max-height: 450px;
     }
   }
   .product-image-gallery {
     position: relative;
   }
   .product-image-gallery .gallery-image {
     display: none;
   }
   .product-image-gallery .gallery-image.visible {
     display: block;
   }
   .product-image-gallery .gallery-image.visible.hidden {
     visibility: hidden;
   }
   .product-image-gallery:before, .product-image-gallery:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: none;
   }
   .product-image-gallery:before {
     background-color: white;
     opacity: 0.8;
     z-index: 2;
   }
   .product-image-gallery:after {
     background-image: url("../images/opc-ajax-loader.gif");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     z-index: 3;
   }
   .product-image-gallery.loading {
     position: relative;
   }
   .product-image-gallery.loading:before, .product-image-gallery.loading:after {
     display: block;
   }

   .product-image-thumbs li {
     display: inline-block;
   }
   .product-image-thumbs li:first-child {
     margin-left: -1px;
   }
   .product-image-thumbs a {
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
   }

   .no-touch .product-image-thumbs a:hover {
     border-color: #c7c7c7;
   }
   ```

Last, but not least, some optimizations to the elevateZoom thanks to Google and finding the following post at [BelVG Blog by Mishel Soiko](http://blog.belvg.com/jquery-zoom-and-slide-plugins-in-magento-1-9.html), I was able to modify and take advantage of more settings for the elevateZoom such as internal zoom or offset of the zoom window, etc. Also, I wanted the image to have a popup fancybox when clicked, which I enabled with help from the above blog down in the comments.

1. Open that **app.js** file you copied over to your theme earlier

   Above line 1153 (`var ProductMediaManager = {`), paste in (copied from the above BelVG blog link):

   ```
   var settings = {

       // set tint background
       tint:true,
       tintColour:'#F90',
       tintOpacity:0.5,

       // Size
       zoomWindowHeight: 300,
       zoomWindowWidth: 400,
       borderSize: 0,

       // Position
       zoomWindowOffetx: 10,
       zoomWindowOffety: 0,

       // Additional settings for Zoomer positioning.
       // zoomWindowPosition: 1,
       // zoomType: "inner",

       // Fade-in speed settings
       zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
       zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
       lensFadeIn: 500,
       lensFadeOut: 500,

       // Ability to zoom by using the mouse scroll.
       scrollZoom : true,

       // inertia - my favorite one 
       easing: true
   }
   ```

   If you want the fancybox popup, at above what is now line 1227, paste in:

   ```
   $j(".product-image-gallery").on("click", function(e) {
       var src = $j('.product-image img.visible').attr('src');
   $j.fancybox(src);
   });
   ```

   **Note, you'll need to have the fancybox js library loading after jQuery in your page.xml or elsewhere in your theme**

   Finally, modify what is now line 1232 (if you did both pastings from above) from:

   ```
   image.elevateZoom();
   ```

   to:

   ```
   image.elevateZoom(settings);
   ```

For an overview of all the zoomer settings, check out the official page describing the [elevateZoom Settings](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/configuration)

And that should get it working. If you're working with a custom theme (as I was) you may have more to do.

Comment: With a little different approach I was able to get the automated image switching working too. In my approach I am using `local.xml` to load all `.js` files in the `head` of the page. I will update my answer when I find some time. Until then you can find a detailed tutorial I wrote on how to do this [here](http://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/use-magento-swatches-in-custom-theme/).

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Configurable Swatches wont change the picture on configurable product

Please check this,

http://ravichomal.blogspot.in/2015/12/rwd-1910-configurable-image-swatches.html