# Magento 1.9.1 swatches don't swap images

Tags: javascript, ce-1.9.1.0, swatches

I've modified my custom template to be able to use swatches with it.
(Applied this solution [How to use Magento 1.9.1.0 Configurable Swatches in Default package theme (or a custom theme)?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a/45949#45949?newreg=1802a237ff544415be27c6bc4ebac36e))

Everything is working fine except swapping images. When I click on color swatches, nothing happening!
I have my labels filled out but still no chance.
When I get to debugging I found the following errors:

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PointerManager
onOptionOver (swatches-product.js, line 483)
(anonymous function) (swatches-product.js, line 319)
(anonymous function) (prototype.js, line 391)
responder (prototype.js, line 5598)

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PointerManager
onOptionOut (swatches-product.js, line 540)
(anonymous function) (swatches-product.js, line 325)
(anonymous function) (prototype.js, line 391)
responder (prototype.js, line 5598)

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $j
updateImage (product-media.js, line 150)
updateSelect (swatches-product.js, line 728)
onOptionClick (swatches-product.js, line 468)
(anonymous function) (swatches-product.js, line 313)
(anonymous function) (prototype.js, line 391)
responder (prototype.js, line 5598)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This link may help you: http://ravichomal.blogspot.in/2015/12/rwd-1910-configurable-image-swatches.html

This is for list page

Comment: This link for view page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299592/how-to-change-configurable-product-main-image-by-associated-product-image-based

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problem, if you go to the rwd folder in both app/skin, copy that over to your theme folder, it will work. what I am fuss about is how many library it need for this to work.

Comment: This link may help you: http://ravichomal.blogspot.in/2015/12/rwd-1910-configurable-image-swatches.html

This is for list page

Comment: This link for view page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299592/how-to-change-configurable-product-main-image-by-associated-product-image-based