# How do you show image tiles as configurable product option?

Tags: configurable-product, frontend, product-images, color-swatches, attribute-options

I am trying to get my configurable products set up as shown below.  I have looked all over and unless I'm using the wrong terms I can't see it anywhere. [image: Image swatches]

To confirm at the moment I have a dropdown input option but I want it to show as the above color option.  I presume as magento have this image on their own website no extension will be needed as they haven't mentioned it in the guide.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the "Configurable Swatches" guide yet, from the Magento dev team?

Answer (score 1):

It's a built in feature since Magento CE 1.9.1 and EE 1.14.1

See:

[Configurable Swatches Guide for Magento EE 1.14.1 and Magento CE 1.9.1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches)

[How to use Magento 1.9.1.0 Configurable Swatches in Default package theme (or a custom theme)?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a)