# configurable swatch products not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have one question regarding configurable swatches.

I have purchased theme forest bizzare theme for magento and i transfer all configurable swatch folder in my bizzare theme.

and in product view page and listing page in color and size get configurable swatch but when i click on color in view or listing page products get blank.

can i know what is the issue and i am done wrong in this.

can you guide me in this what should i do to get product swatch correct on click.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question on configurable Swatches](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70911/question-on-configurable-swatches)

Answer (score 2):

The Magento 1.9.1 configurable swatches module only works with the rwd theme and derivations of it.

There is a free extension that helps you to make it compatible with other themes, you can give it a try: https://github.com/tmhub/catalog-configurable-swatches

Or use a different solution that's independent of themes. I recommend Easylife Switcher by @Marius: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've done more than just copy the swatches folder, if not try following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/45948/27139) answer.

I'm also assuming by "product swatch correct on click" you're wanting the product image to change on swatch selection.

In order for magento to actually find your product images you will need to set the image labels to match the color on your main product, I went into more detail [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70915/27139).