# Question on configurable Swatches

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have several products with different colours. I use Configurables Swatches to display colors but I am having a little trouble it does not show me the colors of products when I click on the color.

To display the colors of products need images on all simple products that are not visible on the site? or only on the configurable product

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up the product images on the configurable product.

The product image labels need to be the colour.

[image: Product Page]

Set your product image labels to be like this:

[image: Admin panel settings]

This should allow the product image to change on swatch selection

[image: Image changing]

Comment: Thank you for your help. but I am having a little trouble. I put as attribute color: green. on my configurable product I put on an image as label: green but it only displays the image do you know why?

Comment: @webevolution What do you mean it only displays the image? Are you talking about it not showing the color on the option itself? if so you need to make another image on the main product with the label color-swatch (charcoal-swatch) and that will be pulled through: [Admin panel settings](http://i.imgur.com/60zpyEh.png), [Frontend output](http://i.imgur.com/U1zeizr.png). If this isn't what you're looking for can you respond with an actual screenshot with what's going wrong.