# Configurable Swatches products in magento 1.9.0.1 version

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1, swatches

can i make a configurable products as like this :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches

in magento 1.9.0.1 version.

as in the post they mentioned it's only from 1.9.1 and after,

what changes i have to make it to work for 1.9.0.1?

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to install extension from **1.9.1.0** Also make sure your current theme should be support this and you have to add some necessary changes to your theme as well

Here very good detail information provide by [@ForMat](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a)

i am sure it will sure work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use Easylife Switcher and it workes for all version from 1.7 - 1.9.0.1. After these version your required features comes by default starting from 1.9.1.x.

Donwload link: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Comment: Right...Best extension ever :)

Comment: I'd actually recommend using Easylife Switcher in Magento 1.9.1 as well, that saves you the pain of integrating your theme (if you are not using Magento's rwd theme)

Comment: @Marius All credit goes to you for this and thx for your work on this.