# Changes configurable product main image to associated simple product image when option selected

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1

Looking for a way that allow change the product image based on the attribute selected for the configurable product.

Configurable Product With Color Options : 1) Red 2) Green

If the Red is selected by user is should change the main image on the details page with the one from associated products.

Requirement: Is this available in default magento version Or should i use extension?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do that with the configurable swatches. They are available with the theme rwd, if you enable them in the configuration (catalog > configurable swatches)

Or you can follow this guide to enable them in another theme : [How to use Magento 1.9.1.0 Configurable Swatches in Default package theme (or a custom theme)?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a)

Comment: I am using version 1.9.0.1 and your provided link is not helpful in that. What should i do?

Comment: You need to activate the configurable swatches for your theme (or try using RWD theme with the configurable swatches activated in the configuration). They are doing exactly what you are asking : Showing the pictures of the associated simple products, depending of the options.

Comment: I am using custom theme and in 1.9.0.1, there is no color swatches.