# Magento configurable swatches on product list in custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches

I'm trying to get configurable swatches to work in my own custom theme, and have followed these instructions: [How to use Magento 1.9.1.0 Configurable Swatches in Default package theme (or a custom theme)?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a)

This works for the product page, but I don't get the swatches showing up in the list view.

The rwd catalog xml file has this entry:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
        </block
    </block
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

if I add in:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
```

To my base theme catalog.xml file in the same spot it works, so what do I put in my theme's xml file to get this to work the same? How do I target the block called product_list to add that core/text_list block into it?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need to add

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
```

after

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

in catalog.xml under catalog_category_layered section and copy

> app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

to your theme

Answer (score 0):

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
```

after

```
 <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

in catalog_category_layered and catalog_category_default also you need to change in list.phtml where ever you want to display swatch add this code

```
    <?php
    // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
    // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
    if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
            echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
        }
    }
?>
```

and add this below code in end of list.phtml

```
    <?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        //set product collection on after blocks
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
        echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```