# Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in configurable.phtml on line 32

Tags: color-swatches, ce-1.9.2.4

I have a Magento v 1.9.2.4 CE  Community Edition site. I am using a custom theme I purchased off a template site. Apparently the theme does not support configurable item swatches. So I followed the tutorial here

[How to use Magento 1.9.1.0 Configurable Swatches in Default package theme (or a custom theme)?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a)

Now when I go to the product I where I would expect to see the swatches I see the below error
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in app/design/frontend/default/ma_sahara_digital3/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml on line 32

The line this refers to is

```
$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
```

I saw some other posts on here about the same issue but none of them have a working resolution?? I am hoping someone might know a fix for this.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

so for some reason there is no attr_renderers block (alias) on the page and so it is not an object.

Did you clear the cache? Just Checking ;)

Another reason could be that the theme you are using changed the layout/catalog.xml file so that the parent block `product.info.options.configurable` does not exist

If the catalog.xml layout is overwritten this should be defined like here: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml#L285