# magento CE 1.9.2 color swatches

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, color-swatches

I am using magento C.E. 1.9.2 built in color swatch functionality.

I have enabled color and size swatches from back-end and I have added one configure product.

When I go to detail page it shows drop-down option instead of swatches.

Can any one help me how to solve this.

Here are the links: category Page: http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets.html

Product details page of Configurable product: http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets/percale-venice-set.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Select color and size in admin

[image: Screenshot]

Also follow these steps to copy files to your theme:

[How to use Magento 1.9.1.0 Configurable Swatches in Default package theme (or a custom theme)?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a)

if you need more help, please comment

Comment: yes, I am a magento developer. I have checked all files too comparing with RWD theme to using theme ultimo.

Comment: Yes, I always follow this step that you sent in the link. My problem is "why did not show swatch images in only  for product details page although it's working fine in category page? " I already spent time as much time for the problem. After failing that i asked you.

Comment: @PankajPramanik is that possible to give me admin setting screen shot because with this 2 step always this will work

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/auXeT

Comment: I added a screshot link " http://imgur.com/a/auXeT"

Comment: please check store view has same selection ? also start red lines from admin and check the configureswtch files call or not

Comment: store view has same selection means? I just set default config , did not create any other store.

Comment: So issue in files please just check all files transfer with link not miss any files.

Comment: can you see it's working fine in category pages http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets.html  ?
But was not showed in product details page  http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets/percale-venice-set.html#product_tabs_description_tabbed/

Comment: I will check which files link, you told me for files issue?

Comment: i just check your view source none of this folder js display -> skin/frontend/RWD/default/js/lib/

Comment: I already added all color swatch images in media/wysiwyg/swatches like for White value white.png

Comment: I am using Ultimo theme

Comment: are u transfer all files which showing in links beuase we must need to transfer this one to works swtaches in custom theme

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/TrsnX

Comment: please check the screenshot http://imgur.com/a/TrsnX

Comment: Ultimo not a custom theme it's a premium theme. So it has already built in color swatch option although I checked it again and again. can you share your email address or skype id?I will be grateful to you.

Comment: sorry i already worked with Ultimo theme you must follow that file step.

Comment: Did you mean will i copy all files  to DEFAULT packages too?

Comment: no copy all files to ultimo/default.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on boolean in E:\xampp\htdocs\parachute\app\design\frontend\ultimo\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml on line 32

Comment: after copying i got an above error

Comment: all files as per document you transfer ?

Comment: this is configure product ?

Comment: this default function only work with configurable product not with custom option.

Comment: make this answer as worked  please

Comment: I could not understand "make this answer as worked ".

Comment: How can i do that? it was my first question in magento  stackexchange. I did  not know how to accept a answer.

Comment: please check here how you can do this http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Can you tell me how can I add like this swatches in simple product too? I can see from ultimo theme demo, they used it for simple product too as custom option value.