# Displaying Configurable Swatches in a Custom Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-images, color-swatches

I used [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45948/how-to-use-magento-1-9-1-0-configurable-swatches-in-default-package-theme-or-a) for adding configurable swatches to my custom theme. It worked but I managed to achieve a partial result.

The problem i am facing is that i see double images on my product-view page. I have attached the screenshots for reference:

[image]

You can see that the product only has 1 image (Also shown in more views) but both the images are displaying. Also, when i hover over the topmost image it shows the elevate zoom feature. And when i hover over the below Image it uses the default zoom function of Magento. Below attached are the images of both the cases.

**Hover Case-1:**

[image: Hover Case-1]

**Hover Case-2:**

[image]

I inspected the element and noticed that there is an extra code that appears which is not in the media.phtml file. Below is the screenshot of the inspect element.
[[image: 3]]
and below is the actual code of template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml file. You can see that i am not calling any image after the .product-image-gallery div.

```
    <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<div class="product-image product-image-zoom">
    <div class="product-image-gallery">
        <img id="image-main"
             class="gallery-image visible"
             src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />

        <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
            <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>"
                 class="gallery-image"
                 src="<?php echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>"
                 data-zoom-image="<?php echo  $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2>
    <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
        <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" data-image-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>"
                     width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after'); ?>
```

In addition to this error, for the configurable products that use colour swatch, the picture doesn't get replaced & keeps on adding at the end of the previous image. As i click on the swatch color, the corresponding product image of that swatch keeps on adding at the end of the previous image. Below is the screenshot of the issue.

[image]

I want to understand how is the  tag being added to the media.phtml file & why are the images being appended at the end of the displayed image.

P.S. i have used all the default configurable swatches files from RWD theme & have not made any edits to those files.

Comment: It would be better if you can share the link of your website.

Comment: @mohit you can check this out. https://golfoy.com/titleist-men-s-tour-tech-adjustable-cap.html

Comment: As per my debugging, it is because all images within **product-image-gallery** tag are shown by default, while in rwd theme only one image is displayed at a time.

Comment: Ok thanks for the effective debugging. How to disable the other images & show one at a time?

Comment: You need to find out which javascript code is making all images shown by default. Or you can write custom javascript code to fix it.